# Using AWS Amplify to create a SNS endpoint. How to do so?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-amplify

For creating a SNS endpoint in Android they give us a tutorial on how to create a SNS endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-platform-endpoint.html

It looks a bit outdated and the methods are depreciated. Currently I am using AWS Amplify for my mobile app. How would I do it using the mobileclient? I can't seem to find any tutorials or docs on it. Could someone explain or link me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you mentioned is for creating a mobile endpoint so that SNS can send push notifications.

The Amplify SDK for Android handles this using [Amazon Pinpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/).  The Amplify docs provide a tutorial on how to setup Push Notifications [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/push-notifications).

Comment: I'm not using pinpoint, I'm using Firebase cloud messaging. My app uses firebase cloud messaging to get the device's token, sends that token to SNS to register my device and to create a mobile endpoint which uses FCM to send a notification back to my device whenever a SNS message is published.

Comment: Sorry if I'm making it confusing but my question is do I have to use the tutorial I mentioned above? Or does Amplify have another set of methods to create an SNS endpoint from my app?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your users to be able to receive mobile push notifications from FCM/GCM... The tutorial walks you through the AWS Strategy for doing this within the Amazon ecosystem, which includes using Amazon Pinpoint. If you follow the tutorial you will be able to send push notifications to your Android users with FCM/GCM using the Amplify SDK for Android.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm planning on redoing the entire thing because I was extremely confused. I did NOT know that you could send a push notification DIRECTLY from sns using a mobile endpoint. I thought we had to use a 3rd part push notification service like FCM, Baidu, etc... as it said here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html ---- "You send push notification messages to both mobile devices and desktops using one of the following supported push notification services: " And it lists a bunch of services plus a image showing the third parties..